# How to split long fraction?

Tags: article-writing

I have a fraction with long numerator,
$$
\frac{x1+\ldots+x50}{y}.
$$
What is preferred in typing? Or something different?

(1) 
$$\frac{x1+x2+}{}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad(\text{first line})\\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\frac{+x3+x4+\ldots+x50}{y}\qquad(\text{second line})
$$
(2)
$$\frac{x1+x2+}{\ldots}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad(\text{first line})\\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\frac{+x3+x4+\ldots+x50}{y}\qquad(\text{second line})
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{y} &\Bigl( x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \\
&\qquad + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 \Bigr)
\end{align}
$$

?

Comment: Maybe this is the simplest :-)